# Programming code that predicts which day of the week it is when given a specific date

Tags: java

I need to write a program that falls under these guidelines:

Write a program DayOfWeek.java that takes a date as input and prints the day of the week that date falls on. Your program should take three command-line arguments: m (month), d (day), and y (year). For m use 1 for January, 2 for February, and so forth. For output print 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so forth. Use the following formulas, for the Gregorian calendar (where / denotes integer division):

```
y0 = y − (14 − m) / 12
x = y0 + y0/4 − y0/100 + y0/400
m0 = m + 12 × ((14 − m) / 12) − 2
d0 = (d + x + 31m0 / 12) mod 7
```

so far this is what I have written

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class DayOfWeek {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

     boolean keepGoing = true;

     while(keepGoing) {
       System.out.println("Month");
       int m = scanner.nextInt();
         if (m < 1 || m > 12) {
           System.out.println("Months are between 1 and 12");
           continue;
         }

       System.out.println("Day");
       int d = scanner.nextInt();
         if (d < 1 || d > 31) {
            System.out.println("Days are between 1 and 31");
            continue;
         }

       System.out.println("Year");
       int y = scanner.nextInt();
         if (y < -10000 || y > 10000) {
            System.out.println("Years are between -10000 and 10000");
            continue;
         }

        int y0 = y - (14 - m) / 12;
        int x = y0 + y0/4 - y0/100 +y0/400;
        int m0 = m + 12 * ((14 - m) / 12) - 2;
        int d0 = (d + x + 31 * m0 / 12) % 7;  
        boolean c = 0 <= d0 <= 6;

          if (c) {
            String b = "Sunday";
          } else {
            if (c) {
              String b = "Monday";
            } else {
              if (c) {
                String b = "Tuesday";
            } else {
              if (c) {
                String b = "Wednesday";
              } else {
                if (c) {
                  String b = "Thursday";
                } else {
                  if (c) {
                    String b = "Friday";
                  } else {
                    if (c) {
                      String b = "Saturday";
                    }                 
                   }
                  }
               }
             }
             }
          } 

        System.out.println("The day of the week is " + b);
    }



  }

 }
```

When I try to run it however it says

```
DayOfWeek.java:36: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='
boolean c = 0 <= d0 <= 6;
                          ^
first type:  boolean
second type: int

DayOfWeek.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("The day of the week is " + b);
                                                      ^
symbol:   variable b
location: class DayOfWeek
2 errors
```

I don't really know how to fix this, can someone please help me. I'm still very new to coding.

Comment: when you code try to name variables in a meaningful manner ie dont use c as a varibale name also look up about the pyramid of doom. That way other people will be able to understand your code.

Comment: That syntax is invalid, and the error message tells you why. Rewrite the code to properly do the comparisons. You've done it in other places in your code. As to the second, look at the scope of where you've declared `b`, and think about how the compiler might see that list of `if..else` statements (and what might happen if none of those conditions are met); where would `b` be declared in that case?

Comment: When do you expect `b` to get something else than "Sunday"?

Comment: By the way, [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) is the name of a class bundled with Java 8 and later.  May be best to choose another name for your class.

Answer (score -2):

The line `boolean c = 0 <= d0 <= 6;` should be `boolean c = 0 <= d0 && d0 <= 6;`

Take a look at the [java specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1) to get an idea of how to use relational operators.

Basically 1 < 0 is of the type boolean and you cannot use smaller than and greater than on a boolean.

Comment: This might be an answer if you explained *why* that line should be written the way you've said it should (and if you were teaching better practices). It's not in its current state.